# Maximum value of function satisfy given inequality

Tags: calculus

> If $f(x)$ is invertiable increasing function such that $f''(x)+2f'(x)\geq 2$ and $f'(0)=2$. Then maximum value of $(f^{-1})'f(x)$

Try: Writting it as $$e^{2x}f''(x)+2e^xf'(x)\geq 2e^{2x}$$

$(e^{2x}f'(x)'\geq 2e^{2x}$. Integrate both side

$$e^{2x}f'(x)\geq e^{2x}+C\Rightarrow f'(x)\geq 1+Ce^{-2x}$$

$$f(x)\geq x-\frac{C}{2}e^{-2x}+D$$

Could some help me how to get maximum of 
$(f^{-1})'f(x)$  from above ,  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\ge 0$. Noting that
$$(e^{2x}f'(x))'\geq 2e^{2x}$$
one has, by integrating both sides from $0$ to $x$,
$$ e^{2x}f'(x)-f'(0)\geq 2\int_0^xe^{2t}dt=e^{2x}-1. $$
Using $f'(0)=2$, one has
$$ f'(x)\ge1+e^{-2x}. $$
Also noting
$$ (f^{-1})'(f(x))=\frac{1}{f'(x)}\le\frac{1}{1+e^{-2x}}\le 1.$$
For $x<0$, we can't obtain the up bound.

Comment: Thanks xpaul, please explain how $\displaystyle (f^{-1})'(f(x))=\frac{1}{f(x)}$

Comment: and i think it is  $\displaystyle \frac{e^{2x}}{1+e^{2x}}<1$ for $x\geq 0$

Comment: @DurgeshTiwari, note $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ and then take derivative.

Comment: Thanks xpul please also explain why $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1+e^{-2x}}\leq 1$ is it not $<1.$